# How to send content of a data base and not [object Objet] Discord.js + mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js, bots

I'm coding a DiscordBot that can take the informations from my database and send them in the discord chanel but the problem is that only send in the channel : [object Object] ...
If someone have an idea for send the informations and not [object Object] ...

This is the code of the command :

```
const { Channel } = require('discord.js');
const { MESSAGES } = require('../../utility/constants');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require("mysql");



const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "devoirs",

})

db.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Connecter a la BDD')
})


module.exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {

   
    db.query("SELECT * FROM devfr ", function (err, test){
            console.log(test)
            message.channel.send(test)
            return test
     })
};




module.exports.help = MESSAGES.COMMANDS.COMMANDES.DEVOIRS;
```

And the result :

[Tis is the command is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQlUY.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: tu peux envoyer le contenu du console.log(test)?

Comment: Voilà ce qui es afficher :

(3) [RowDataPacket, RowDataPacket, RowDataPacket]
0:RowDataPacket {Français: 'bonjour'}
1:RowDataPacket {Français: 'bonsoir'}
2:RowDataPacket {Français: 'bonsoir'}
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)

Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.map` notation:

```js
db.query("SELECT * FROM devfr ", function (err, test){
    console.log(test)
    message.channel.send(test.map((row) => row.Français))
    return test
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to take each data for put it in an embed or anything like that ? With the map , that send every data in one time. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use embed.setDescription()